# SQL Indexed Views : what happens if data has changed

Tags: sql, view, indexed

I undestand what indexed view are but i wonder what exactly happens when the data in underlaying table(s) has been changed?
Is entire view cache discarded od just changed rows?

I have very complex query on several tables(+5) which is used for searching hotels availability(+100k records) and IMHO indexed view could improves performance significantly.
But the data(few rows) are changed frequently(room was sold, free rooms altered in admin atc.) and if the view would be rebuild each time when just one row was changed, would be bottle neck for my app.

Or any ideas how to "cache" very coplex queries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the technet documentation:

> Unlike ordinary indexes, a single row
>   insert into any of the participating
>   tables may cause multiple row changes
>   in an indexed view. This is because
>   the single row may join with multiple
>   rows of another table. The same is
>   true for updates and deletes.
>   Consequently, the maintenance of an
>   indexed view may be more expensive
>   than maintaining an index on the
>   table.

Source:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx#XSLTsection124121120120

i.e. it sounds as though rows are updated where relevant, without necessarily having to update/recreate the view in its entirety.

Comment: I have rewriten my SP using indexed view and performance is shocking!. I hope there will be no big additional maintenance in rebuilding indexed view.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running sql server. 100k+ rows is not a lot. If you are joining 5ish tables I would suggest that you made sure there are covering indexes on the columns you are joining before considering implementing indexed views. Use the query analyzer to find the bottle neck in your query directly. If you are having performance problems on so small tables there are probably nasty table scans in there.

Comment: If you've got a performance issue joining 5 tables of 100k rows then I suspect there's an issue somewhere in the query, so moving that into an indexed view will just make the database server rerun the inefficient query more often.

I'd suggest reviewing the execution plan for the original query, looking out for table scans in particular, to see if you can rework that and / or improve indexes to get it running faster before working further on indexed views.

Comment: Hi.
Checking Execution Plan for Table Scans(and simmilar slow tasks) is the first thing i always do when tunning SQL scripts. The query had a lot of UDF, after i moved them to indexed view they are not calculated all the time, and the performace is great.